# My computer won't boot off a Windows install DVD - it goes directly to Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7

I installed Ubuntu, but now I want to install Windows again. The problem is not in the installation of Windows, but that my PC won't boot off the DVD drive. The DVD drive is the first boot option in the BIOS but it doesn't open any of the DVDs I put in.  It doesn't seems to do anything because I can't hear the noise of the drive.  The disc moves, but not enough and then the PC boots into Ubuntu. What can I do?

Comment: It sounds like a hardware problem. If DVD drive does not work before Ubuntu even starts, then either the DVD drive is bad or the DVD is bad.

Comment: I tried, differents dvds, and it doesn't seems to work. The DVD drive is working, but I don't understand whygoes direct to ubuntu. One of the DVDs even opens inside ubuntu but being a windows .exe doen't works at all.

Comment: Can you install off a USB? http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/a/install-windows-7-usb.htm

Comment: I don't have any USB right now :/. I was wondering if this is related to a ubuntu 64 bits and windows discs 32 bits. A moment ago, it opened a 32 bits ubuntu repair disc but since 32-64 isn't compatible didin't worked but, at leats worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the DVD is working by playing a movie or music. If ok, then proceed as follows.

1. Go to bios set up. Press 'Del' repeatedly to start bios set up at boot time.
2. change boot sequence to DVD drive and then hardisk
3. If you install win xx, you are likely to lose all the ubuntu data as windows will remove the ubuntu boot info.
4. Before doing anything, do bakup.
5. If still there is boot problem, check your win boot DVD.

Answer (score 0):

check if the windows DVD is bootable or not by testing it on other computer

on most computers you can select the boot device by clicking the F12 key during boot and select the desired boot device

also would recommend using a USB for installation as DVD often get scratches and may fail to install some files during installation